# Tailwind-elements accordion not functioning after refresh or npm run dev/build. Saving the page after a refresh, however, works

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, tailwind-elements

Copy-pasting code for a tailwind-elements works perfectly in my vite-react app. Refreshing the page or running npm run dev breaks it.

https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/accordion/

I followed the step by step instructions to get it started. When I copy-paste the code for an accordion ( or any of the other drop down types of elements ) they work perfectly. But when I refresh my page or do an npm run dev and npm run build, the accordion just stops dropping down. But when I ctrl+s to save it, it works again for that session.

import React from 'react'
import {
Collapse,
initTE,
} from "tw-elements";

initTE({ Collapse });

function Filters() {
return (

```
    <span
      class="-mr-1 ml-auto h-5 w-5 shrink-0 rotate-[-180deg] fill-[#336dec] transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:mr-0 group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:rotate-0 group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:fill-[#212529] motion-reduce:transition-none dark:fill-blue-300 dark:group-[[data-te-collapse-collapsed]]:fill-white">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        strokeWidth="1.5"
        stroke="currentColor"
        class="h-6 w-6">
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>
</h2>
<div
  id="collapseTwo"
  class="!visible hidden"
  data-te-collapse-item
  aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
  data-te-parent="#accordionExample">
  <div class="px-5 py-4">
    <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is
    hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate
    classes that we use to style each element. These classes control
    the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS
    transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
    overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just
    about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>,
    though the transition does limit overflow.
  </div>
</div>
```

)
}

export default Filters